# $X_{n}$ independent and there is $a_{n}\to0$ s.t $\lim\limits _{m\to\infty}a_{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}X_{n}$ is finite w.p 1. Then the limit is constant.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I'm trying to prove the following claim:
Suppose $X_{1},X_{2},...$
  are independent and there exists a sequence $\left\{ a_{n}\right\} _{n\geq1}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$
  s.t $\lim\limits _{n\to\infty}a_{n}=0$
  and $\lim\limits _{m\to\infty}a_{m}\sum_{n=1}^{m}X_{n}$
  exists and is finite with probability 1. Then the limit must be constant.

I don't really have a direction so I would appreciate a good hint for where to start from.

Comment: Hint: Kolmogorov zero-one law.

Comment: More specifically, use the Kolmogorov's 0-1 law to argue that for any interval, the probability that the limit lies in it is either 0 or 1. You can use this, possibly mixing this with sort of bisection argument, to claim that the limit is constant a.s.

Comment: @SangchulLee What sort of bisection will work though? I need a bisection that will gradually be reduced to a singleton.

Comment: You may begin with any interval which contains the limit a.s. The for each 2 bisected subintervals, at least one of the subintervals (if you are using non-overlapping subintervals, or exactly one of them if you are using disjoint subintervals) contains the limit a.s. We can repeatedly apply this argument to find a nested sequence of intervals $I_n$ s.t. each $I_n$ contains the limit a.s. and the diameter goes to 0.

Comment: @SangchulLee The assumption tells me that the limit exists and is finite a.s but not that it is always the same (i.e) constant which is what I'm trying to show. In order to use the argument you suggest it seems to me I need to know that the value of the limit is also bounded in order to make sure that I can start with an interval that contains the limit a.s. Why is this true?

Comment: That is where we need Kolmogorov's 0-1 law. You first need to establish that your event (that the limit converges) lies in the tail $\sigma$-algebra. Then the theorem tells us that any event regarding the limiting r.v. is trivial, i.e. has probability either 0 or 1.